# Matlab do not regress if any Y is zero in loop

Tags: matlab, regression, linear-regression, nan

I am using regress to perform linear regression on a large nc file (containing lat, lon, time, and temperature). So for each lat, lon, temperature is regressed over 30 years (one measurement each year).

In some years, some temperatures are 0 K, in those cases I want the loop to not regress, so the final mean slope does not include these.

Below is the important part of my code.

I am not getting an error but also not getting any difference in whether i include  y(y==0) = NaN;, so I think there may be a better way. I had understood that regress ignores these automatically, but that also appears to not be the case.

```
% initialise time parameters
time_begin  = [1981, 1, 1, 0,0,0];
time_end    = [2010,12,31,23,0,0];
years       = (time_begin(1):time_end(1))';
nyears      = length(years);
% create storage and regress
TXx = randi(100, 288, 192, 30);
lat = rand(192, 1);
lon = rand(288, 1);
time = rand(30,1);
M = numel(lon);
N = numel(lat);
slope = zeros(M, N);
intercept = zeros(M, N);
T = numel(time);
x = ([ones(T, 1) years]);
% Regress each lat/lon location
for i = 1 : M
    for j = 1 : N
        % Get all time instances of each lat/lon location
        y = squeeze(TXx(i, j, :));
        y(y==0) = NaN;
        % Create regression problem and solve
        c = regress(y, x);
        intercept(i, j) = c(1);
        slope(i, j) = c(2);      
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NaN's are being ignored, but not in the way you want... The individual data points are ignored, not the entire data set, and thus still a regression is made.

You could simply add a simple check using an `if` statement,

```
for i = 1 : M
   for j = 1 : N
        % Get all time instances of each lat/lon location
        y = squeeze(TXx(i, j, :));
        if ~any(y==0)
            % Create regression problem and solve
            c = regress(y, x);
            intercept(i, j) = c(1);
            slope(i, j) = c(2);      
        end
    end
end
```